# Slack WebHook , Can I send a silent message

Tags: slack-api

My bot sends 2-3 messages at a time as apart of the conversation. This can get annoying when Slack beeps for every message. Is there a way to silence this. Facebook allows me to set a message type to silent to prevent beeps

Comment: not sure, but maybe setting the topic is silent, or something similar like that, might be good for oneliner messages to avoid beeping

Comment: probably found solution, setting a reminder seems to be silent but visible for people in channel (deleting is invisible to others)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not "silence flag" for messages in Slack. Here are your other options to prevent "beeps":

**Mute channel**

You can mute a channel so you wont get any notification for it. See [this link](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204411433-Mute-a-channel) for our to mute channel in your Slack client.

**Notification settings**

You can turn-off the "beeps" for every new message, but still get visual notifications about new messages. See [this link](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201649323-Channel-notification-preferences) for how to change notification settings.